# action parameter returning null

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

There are some similar posts already here, and tried every solution suggested, and still does not work... I can not get value inside controller, it is always null. Below is the code. Am I missing something?

**Client side javascript**

```
 var arr = [];
        $('.myForm').each(function () {
            var ids = {
               n:$('#name').val(),
                c: $('#student_class').val(),
                g: $('#gender').val(),
                p: $('#phone').val()
            }
            arr.push(ids);

        });
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/InsertStudent/",
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            datatype:"html",
            data: JSON.stringify(arr),
            success: function (result) {
                alert("success");
               // $(" ").html(result)
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("error");
            }
        });
```

**MVC Controller**

```
 public PartialViewResult InsertStudent(StudentData model)
    {
        return PartialView();
    }
```

**Model Class**

```
 public class StudentData
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string student_class{ get; set; }
    public bool gender { get; set; }
    public int phone { get; set; }
}
```

**My View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div><input type="button" value="Admin" id="admin" class="btn btn-default" onclick="Admin()" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div><input type="button" value="Student" id="student" class="btn btn-default" onclick="Student()" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div id="partial">
                @*@{ Html.Partial("InsertStudent");}*@
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
                    }
```

Comment: what is the type of StudentData?

Comment: StudentData is the model Class name.Can anyone please suggest what i am doing wrong?I am new to programming.Thanks

Comment: you are sending array to server and what server actually hopes to see seems to be single object not array.

Comment: change your method parameter to List<StudentData> model

Comment: Still it is giving null values.

Comment: Are you just submitting a form to the server? Can you show your entire view?

Comment: sure...........

Comment: depending if your view is strongly-typed to the class `StudentData` try changing this - `data: JSON.stringify(arr)` to `$("form").serialize()`

Comment: Also, for a form.. shouldn't you have an `input` that is `type="submit"`?

Comment: @anjali your javascript property object names should match the StudentDataobject property  names

Comment: change you ids variable declaration like this :
var ids = {
name :$('#name').val(),
student_class: $('#student_class').val(),
gender : $('#gender').val(),
phone : $('#phone').val()
}

Comment: you've declared a single StudentData model as action paramater. and you are send an array of javascript object. Change the declaration in MVC C# action method or just send single javscript object .

Comment: can you show "InsertStudent" partial view code @anjali

Answer (score 0):

Change the button's type attribute to button.
Make the following changes in Javascript :

function save(){

```
     // var arr = []; Comment out the array
     var ids; // Declare ids out side the eachloop

                   var ids = {
      name :$('#name').val(),
      student_class: $('#student_class').val(),
      gender : $('#gender').val(),
      phone : $('#phone').val()
}
                  //  arr.push(ids); //Comment out this 


                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Home/InsertStudent/",
                    type: "POST",
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    datatype:"html",
                    data: JSON.stringify(ids), // send ids instead of array
                    success: function (result) {
                        alert("success");
                       // $(" ").html(result)
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("error");
                    }
                });
```

}

Comment: Is there any html dom with class myForm ?
I cannot find any form element with myForm class or input elements in your view

Comment: Can you share your entire view code including partial view code (if any)

Answer (score 0):

```
@model Demo.Models.StudentData
@{
ViewBag.Title = "InsertStudent";
}

<div class="jumbotron text-center">
<h3>Student Portal</h3>
<p>Please enter your information here....</p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
<div class="container">
    <div class="myForm">
    <div class="form-group row">
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.id)
@Html.Label("Name")
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.name)
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        @Html.Label("Class")
        @Html.DropDownList("student_class", new List<SelectListItem>
   {new SelectListItem {Text="I",Value="1" },
   new SelectListItem {Text="II",Value="2" },
   new SelectListItem {Text="III",Value="3" },
       new SelectListItem {Text="IV",Value="4" },
       new SelectListItem {Text="V",Value="5" }
   }, "select")
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        @Html.Label("Gender")
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.gender, "M", true) Male
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.gender, "F", false) Female
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        @Html.Label("Phone")
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.phone)
    </div>
                <input type="submit" value="Save" onclick="Save()"/>
            </div>
```

Comment: hi I've updated my answer change the button's input type attribute to button (instead of submit in your partial view) as you are calling save function on button. And place the given javascript code inside Save function.

Comment: Also I've update JavaScript by removing $('.myForm').each() and placed all the code out side.